# file does not exist 500.shtml and 404.shtml in joomla internal server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, joomla2.5

today i encountered a very weird problem on joomla that is file does not exist 500.shtml and 400.shtml. In my every web page no matter what i am trying to open it is showing me the same error over and over again which turned off my website. I also google out for it and found some suggestions that are turn off your sef in config file of joomla or change your htaccess by putting a # in front of option and close the htaccess file but still it does not helped me. Any help would be appreciated the most.

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache after turning off your sef? Also please try to disable .htaccess by renaming it to something like disabled.htaccess.
Please let me know if it helps, then we will find a solution how to fix that.

Comment: I tried it already but still it is not working. I also made 404.shtml and 500.shtml page and now my site has been redirecting to 500.shtml page

Comment: Now it has started working it was my hosting issue. I really don't know what they have done or modified and now it is working again. They only told me it was a server side issue, they took 30 mins and told me to restart my server after that everything has been working back again :)

Answer (score 1):

In general the first step when dealing with this sort of error would be to turn on error reporting by putting the following at the beginning of your index.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Doing so might give you some php-specific error message with which I will find it easier to trouble shoot the problem.
This would Display the real error , I had a same trouble, and I found that a new template/plugin/module were creating the problem .So I uninstalled/disabled it .And it was working again.
Cheeers